# why is an integer type sent upside down?

Tags: c, endianness, mailslot

I am making a server program and a client have sent various data like string, integer.

when a client program sent me string, 
I recieved in regular sequence.

for example,

a client sent me "hello"
I have recieved 
h e l l o \0

However, a client sent me integer like 12345
I received upside down.

for example)

a client wants to send me 12345(integer type)
he or she sent '30''39''\0'
and I recieved '57''48''\0' ('57' is dec of '0x39' and '48' is dec of '0x30')

I found that the value was sent upside down and I thought that was because of network byte order.
However, I didn't use network and I had client and server program. 
In other word, 
I sent myself data and my computer is not connected with internet.

I communicate with a client by using a mail slot in c language.
why was integer type sent upside down?

Comment: Read this please — http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: What was sent is the same as what was received, so you are probably mistaken and `0x39` `0x30` was sent in the first place.  It would make your question clearer if you use hex notation for hex value instead of writing apostrophes for both hex and dec. Also show the code where you are sending and receiving.

Answer (score 0):

The socket-related functions use big-endian to store your integers for some functions. You'll have to translate them with the available functions, or you can write your own macros to do it, which isn't difficult.